# How to parse HTML tags from currently viewing website?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Forgive me for a long post, but I need to explain my problem clearly before anyone fires the down-vote button blindly.

I have worked on Java/Android/Python/C/C++ but my present technology stack does not seem to help me in solving my current problem as i dont have much experience in web technologies, so I am asking for help.

I have a webpage from a website(which has to be logged in & it generates token for every login) where I do some data input, I want to parse the HTML code of the webpage which I am currently viewing & do some calculation based on the value of few of the tags present in the webpage.

I have tried python's beautifulsoup but I am not able to login to the website(i tried mechanize).

I tried to use OCR in python but that did not give the desired result.

**So I need help/suggestion which language combination should I choose such that I can scrape & process the currently viewing webpage's HTML tags & display a result.**

```
def count_pokemon_total():
    f = open("s.txt")
    types = {"pikachu:-":0,"raichu:-":320,'Pichu:-': 470}
    pokemon=[]
    contents = f.read()
    for t in types:
        if t in contents:
            print "Number of ",t,"are",contents.count(t)
            pokemon.append(contents.count(t)*types[t])

    print "total pokemon values are is",sum(pokemon),"Rs."
    f.close()

count_pokemon_total()
```

P.S.:- Attaching the code which I have tried & it works but I dont want to use this approach.

P.P.S. :- the code attached is just for understanding what I am trying to achieve, it is not related to pokemon anyhow.

Comment: What is wrong w/ the approach you currently have?

Comment: Javascript has full access to the page in which it's running.  You can very easily get data from the page, so I'm not sure what your problem is.  Can you change the page content to include a Javascript link?

Comment: You're using a web browser to view the page, right? The most direct way to work with the page contents therefore would be a JavaScript bookmarklet or browser add-on (bookmarklet would be much simpler).

Comment: @ScottHunter the problem with the approach is I will need to copy the contents of html page & put it in to a file & make the script read the file, few of my users will not be well versed copying the html code(non technical users)

Comment: @Archer no, I cannot edit the webpage & add a Js link

Comment: See @Pointy's approach then.  Write some Javascript that runs successfully in the browser console and then simply save it as a bookmarklet.

Comment: @Archer let me try that, never heard of bookmarklet, glad that i asked here :-)

Comment: Once you start you'll never stop.  I've got a bookmarklet folder in my bookmarks bar and it's getting very, very big :D  Just shout if you need help.

Comment: @Archer will it be possible to convert my python script given above into bookmarklet

Comment: You won't be able to open and read a file, but I assume you actually want to read the current page, so yes.  That's possible.

Comment: @Archer if you have answer/code to the question you can answer it, I will accept it

Comment: Have a go yourself.  Once you've got some code and you need some help then edit the question and post that instead of what's above.  Here's a starting point... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Is it possible to write bookmarklet in python ?

Comment: @Archer Can you check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386888/cant-read-a-webpages-source-code-by-javascript